# $attachment->post_title not displaying title

Tags: posts, post-thumbnails

I have this little piece of php.

```
$attr = array(
            'class' => 'bigImg',
            'alt' => trim(strip_tags( $attachment->post_excerpt )),
            'title' => trim(strip_tags( $attachment->post_title )) );
```

I have this in the html:

```
<?php echo the_post_thumbnail( 'featured', $attr ); ?>
```

and as you might have guessed I want to output the alt and title from the post, but it doesn't seem to be doing it. 
Here's the output:

```
<img width="1081" height="608" src="http://lart.co.uk/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/img4.jpg" class="bigImg wp-post-image" alt="" title="" />
```

So why do I have no title and alt?

Comment: Please read into PHP.net and Codex. This is not a WP question.

Comment: @kaiser I have seen similar posts like this on here. I have read the codex. Do you not know the answer to my question?

Comment: "Do you not know the answer to my question" is maybe not the worst attitude I've seen, but certainly one that immediately disqualifies you from being part of those people I'd be glad to help. I'd suggest you rethink and adjust your attitude sooner than later. And that not just here - I'd venture to guess that most communities, be it online or just outside your door, will *not* welcome such an attitude. Why anybody would upvote such a heinous comment is beyond my understanding.

Comment: Just a by the way: `<?php echo the_post_thumbnail(); ?>` is wrong. it should either be `<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>` or `<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?>`

Comment: @JohannesPille it was late, I was agitated, sorry.

Comment: @JohannesPille I should also state that being told to go away and read php and codex is not exactly helping me, neither does it explain why this not a WP question.

Comment: @kaiser perhaps you could have pointed me to a particular part of the codex, perhaps wp_get_attachment_image() might have been useful. Perhaps I could have asked this first, but what's done is done.

Comment: I am not going to argue this further, I spoke my mind yesterday and am at peace with myself, you and everybody else in the world. As for the technical part, see my below answer.

Comment: Kyle, where should I've pointed you? At php.net and Error display? At Codex and `the_post_thumbnail()`? Both are so obvious that I didn't mind. And when you read the Codex page, then you'll instantly see that the `echo` isn't needed and therefore you should get an Error. No Error = no debugging and so on.

Comment: @kaiser ok, fair enough, but how was my question not a WP question? Is asking for information on a WP function, perhaps more information on the WP loop, not excepted on this site?

Answer (score 1):

**1.** [`the_post_thumbnail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail)...

... is a wrapper for [`echo get_the_post_thumbnail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail). Hence the `echo` construct you are using is redundant. That's not the core of your problem, but worth noting.

**2.** The empty attributes

In your HTML output, the attributes are empty, but they are created.

That leads to the likely conclusion, that the culprit is not `the_post_thumbnail`, but that the values for `$attr['alt']` and `$attr['title']` are empty.

If that's the case, both `trim(strip_tags( $attachment->post_excerpt ))` and `trim(strip_tags( $attachment->post_title ))` must return empty strings.

You can verify (or falsify) that conclusion in two ways:

- By passing static strings to the `$attr` array.
  Are the attributes being populated?
  That would mean the function works.
- By dumping the questionable expressions output:
  `var_dump( trim(strip_tags( $attachment->post_title )) );`
  I would venture to guess that'll output `string(0) ""`

If that's the case, the next question is "why?"
And that can't be answered conclusively without further information.
That might be disappointing, but is a good segue to:

**3.** [`WP_DEBUG`](http://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG)

While developing, set that constant to `true`
It will both help you personally as well as make it possible for you to provide pertinent information when seeking help.

Answer (score 0):

Question is: where does `$attachment` comes from in your code.

Also, i think you are looking for the `wp_get_attachment_image()` function, to be able to access the image attribute values.

Check this example, taken from the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image):

```
$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'attachment',
   'numberposts' => -1,
   'post_status' => null,
   'post_parent' => $post->ID
  );

  $attachments = get_posts( $args ); // gets all images attached to the post
     if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
           echo '<li>';
           echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'full' );
           echo '<p>';
           echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $attachment->post_title );
           echo '</p></li>';
          }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress removed the image title as of version 3.5.

I use these functions in my theme's functions.php to bring it back:

```
add_filter( 'media_send_to_editor', 'rgbtoi_restore_image_title', 15, 2 );
function rgbtoi_restore_image_title( $html, $id ) {
    $attachment = get_post($id);
    if (strpos($html, "title=")) {
        return $html;
    } else {
        $mytitle = esc_attr($attachment->post_title);
        return str_replace('<img', '<img title="' . $mytitle . '" '  , $html);      
    }
}
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_attributes','rgbtoi_image_titles', 10, 2);
function rgbtoi_image_titles($atts,$img) {
    $atts['title'] = trim(strip_tags( $img->post_title ));
    return $atts;
}
```

Comment: Granted, `'title'` was removed from the *default attributes*. But *not* in the context of the OP's question. `the_post_thumbnail` is a wrapper for `echo get_post_thumbnail`, which in turn calls `wp_get_attachment_image`. The latter function then does this: `foreach ( $attr as $name => $value ) { $html .= " $name=" . '"' . $value . '"'; }` (see [lines 568 to 570 of *wp-includes/media.php*](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/media.php#L544)). You can pass *any attribute* and it will append it to the output html - which, incidentally, your filter callback makes use of.

Comment: Point taken! I should read more carefully next time...